# How to make a keyboard component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

There are two inputs into which the user enters numbers. You need to compare these numbers and display an error under the input, if the focus is in the first input and we enter a number and it is less than the number in the second input, then under the first input you need to display the error 'Error first input', and if the focus is in the second input and we enter a number and this number is greater than the number in the first input, then under the second input we display the error 'Error in the second input'. In principle, the conditions for checking will be the same in number, but the error output should be under the input in which the number was entered. Here is my screen with inputs.

```
import { ChangeEvent, FC, memo } from 'react';
import { Translated, useBack, TranslatedString, Form, useTheme } from '@spatium/styled-system';
import { Input, RectangleSurface } from '@spatium/components';
import { Column, Spacing, Text, theme, Theme } from '@spatium/theme';

import { BackButton } from 'components/back-button';
import { ChatButton } from 'components/chat-button';
import { DisplayCurrency } from '@spatium/model';
import { HeadedView } from '@spatium/views';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { StyledInput, CurrencyInput } from './manage-limits.styles';

export type Limit = {
  min: number;
  max: number;
  step: number;
  currentValue: number;
};

export type ManageLimitsViewProps = {
  onBack: (dailyQuantityLimit: number, dailyValueLimit: number, singleTransactionValueLimit: number) => void;
  dailyTrnsnLimit: Limit;
  dailyVolLimit: Limit;
  singleTrnsnLimit: Limit;
  currency: DisplayCurrency;
};

export const ManageLimitsView: FC<ManageLimitsViewProps> = memo(({
  onBack,
  dailyTrnsnLimit,
  dailyVolLimit,
  singleTrnsnLimit,
  currency,
}) => {
  const {
    register,
    watch,
    handleSubmit,
  } = useForm({
    mode: 'onChange',
    defaultValues: {
      dtl: dailyTrnsnLimit.currentValue,
      dvl: dailyVolLimit.currentValue,
      stl: singleTrnsnLimit.currentValue,
    },
  });
  const { mode } = useTheme<Theme>();
  const [ dtl, dvl, stl ] = watch([ 'dtl', 'dvl', 'stl' ]);
  const onUseBack = useBack(() => onBack(dtl, dvl, stl), [dtl, dvl, stl, onBack]);
  
  const handleInput = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const input = e.currentTarget;
    const maxLength = parseInt(input.max);
    const sanitizedValue = input.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); 
    if (sanitizedValue.length > maxLength) {
      input.value = sanitizedValue.slice(0, maxLength);
    } else {
      input.value = sanitizedValue;
    }
  };
  
  console.log('12345', typeof dtl, typeof dvl, typeof stl);
  return (
    <HeadedView
      right={<ChatButton />}
      left={<BackButton onClick={onUseBack} />}
    >
      <Column themePadding={[theme.space(0), theme.spaces.side]} horizontalAlign="stretch">
        <Text
          themeFont={theme.fonts.L}
          themeTextColor={theme.colors.foreground}
        >
          <Translated id="manage-limits.limits" />
        </Text>

        <Spacing themeSpace={theme.space(10)} />
        
        <Text
          themeFont={theme.fonts.C}
          themeTextColor={theme.colors.foreground.alt(1)}
        >
          <Translated id="two-factor-dashboard.describe-limits" />
        </Text>

        <Spacing themeSpace={theme.space(30)} />
        <Form id="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onUseBack)}>
         
          <TranslatedString id="manage-limits.dtl">
            {(translated) => (
              <StyledInput>
                <Input
                  inputMode="numeric"
                  maxLength={7}
                  active={!!dtl}
                  placeholder={translated}
                  {...register('dtl')}
                  onInput={handleInput}
                />
                <CurrencyInput>
                  <RectangleSurface themePadding={theme.space(0)} themeColor={ mode === 'dark' ? theme.colors.surface.alt(2) : theme.colors.surface.alt(1)}>
                    <Text themeTextColor={theme.colors.blue} themeFont={theme.fonts.HT2} themePadding={[theme.space(2), theme.space(6)]}>
                      {currency.toUpperCase()}
                    </Text>
                  </RectangleSurface>
                </CurrencyInput>
              </StyledInput>
            )}
          </TranslatedString>
        
          <Spacing themeSpace={theme.space(30)} />

          <TranslatedString id="manage-limits.dvl">
            {(translated) => (
              <Input
                inputMode="numeric"
                maxLength={7}
                active={!!dvl}
                placeholder={translated}
                {...register('dvl')}
                onInput={handleInput}
              />
            )}
          </TranslatedString>

          <Spacing themeSpace={theme.space(30)} />

          <TranslatedString id="manage-limits.stl">
            {(translated) => (
              <StyledInput>
                <Input
                  inputMode="numeric"
                  maxLength={7}
                  active={!!stl}
                  placeholder={translated}
                  {...register('stl')}
                  onInput={handleInput}
                />
                <CurrencyInput>
                  <RectangleSurface themePadding={theme.space(0)} themeColor={ mode === 'dark' ? theme.colors.surface.alt(2) : theme.colors.surface.alt(1)}>
                    <Text themeTextColor={theme.colors.blue} themeFont={theme.fonts.HT2} themePadding={[theme.space(2), theme.space(6)]}>
                      {currency.toUpperCase()}
                    </Text>
                  </RectangleSurface>
                </CurrencyInput>
              </StyledInput>
            )}
          </TranslatedString>
        </Form> 
      </Column>
    </HeadedView>
  );
});
```

I tried to make the keyboard a separate component, but I can’t track the input that was entered in order to write there the number that was pressed on the on-screen keyboard